# iTerm2 - Split vertically with current profile with same working directory

Tags: iterm

When *splitting vertically with current profile* by using the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, is it possible for the new iTerm2 window to have the same working directory as the current one?

By default, invoking this command opens the new window with the users home directory as the current directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Apple hardware or software as defined in the Help Center <https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic>

Comment: @Mark Questions about applications running on macOS fall under the "third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products." terms mentioned on the page you tried to link, so this is clearly on-topic. If you want to discuss the scope of this please raise a question on Meta.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Open iTerm2 preferences by using the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or by invoking the command iTerm2 → Preferences... in the Menu bar.

In the Preferences window, switch to **Profiles** tab and under **Working Directory** select **Advanced Configuration**. (The default selection is **Home directory**.)

[image]

Now, click on the **Edit...** button, and in the pane that opens, under **Working Directory for New Split Panes** select **Reuse previous session's directory**. (The default selection is **Home directory**.)

[image]

Now, when invoking the **Splitting Vertically with Current Profile** command by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> keys, the adjoining window will be opened with the same directory as the current working directory.

Comment: Is it possible at the same time to open home dir on Command + T ?

Comment: @mrgloomin you can see *New Tabs* configuration just above *Split Panes* configuration

Comment: This is a lifesaver. For years I would do `pwd | pbcopy` and paste the path in the new pane…

Comment: This appears to not work nowadays with iTerm2 3.4.19