# iTerm2 - Split and connect to same host

Tags: terminal, ssh, iterm, fish

When splitting with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, is it possible to have iTerm2 SSH to the same host as the previous pane?

I'm looking for an option like is mentioned in the post [iTerm2 - Split vertically with current profile with same working directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337377/iterm2-split-vertically-with-current-profile-with-same-working-directory) but with a host instead of a working directory. I'm using fish if it matters.